# fscanf() / sscanf() - Match variable length Whitespace?

Tags: php, parsing, printf, scanf

I would to use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) or (preferably) [`fscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) to scan `/proc/meminfo` and return `MemTotal`:

```
MemTotal:        1027156 kB
MemFree:          774596 kB
Buffers:           23816 kB
Cached:           198300 kB
```

Since the number of spaces between `MemTotal:` and the actual number varies, I'm wondering if `sscanf()` is smart enough to parse something like:

```
sscanf($line, "MemTotal:\s+%d");
```

Will the padding and alignment specifiers of `sprintf()` work with `sscanf()` as well?

I would try this out on my own, but I don't have a dev / Linux environment available ATM.

Comment: No, `sscanf` does not understand regular expressions. Yes, the format specifiers for `sscanf` and `sprintf` are identical.

Comment: No, the format  specifiers for `sscanf()` are not identical to `sprintf()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#:~:text=The%20interpreted%20format,with%20following%20differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `sscanf` is smart enough to parse that with an arbitrary number of spaces between. You don't even need to specify it in any special way. Just do

```
sscanf($line, '%s%d');
```

and you'll get

```
Array
(
    [0] => MemTotal:
    [1] => 1027156
)
```

Unfortunately, the PHP Manual isn't too complete about what you can use as the format string, but since it's based on the UNIX command, you can look at other documentations to find what options you have:

- http://docs.roxen.com/pike/7.0/tutorial/strings/sscanf.xml
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

It's a bit fiddly to get them working though.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating the problem. I'd recommend this approach for converting `/proc/meminfo` in a future-proof associative array:

```
$input = file_get_contents('/proc/meminfo');
$data = [];
$hits = preg_match_all('/^(.*):\s+([0-9]+)/m', $input, $matches);
for($i = 0; $i != $hits; $i++)
    $data[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
var_dump($data);
```

[Sample output](http://eval.in/29318):

```
array(45) {
  ["MemTotal"]=>
  string(6) "508856"
  ["MemFree"]=>
  string(5) "33984"
  ["Buffers"]=>
  string(6) "189124"
  ["Cached"]=>
  string(6) "207512"
  ...etc...
```